# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column website.sequence does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, odoo

I got the above error when I restarted the odoo server in docker when a user from our team was making changes to an odoo module. afterwards I was not able to restart odoo.

when i Use \d website the column sequence don't exist in the table.
and when il add the column manualy i have another error for another table.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 90, in lookup

    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/website/models/website.py", line 987, in _get_current_website_id

    found_websites = self.search([('domain', 'ilike', _remove_port(domain_name))]).sorted('country_group_ids')

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 1811, in search

    return res if count else self.browse(res)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5144, in browse

    if not ids:

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/osv/query.py", line 215, in __bool__

    return bool(self._result)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/func.py", line 26, in __get__

    value = self.fget(obj)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/osv/query.py", line 208, in _result

    self._cr.execute(query_str, params)

  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in execute

    

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 89, in check

    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 310, in execute

    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)

psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column website.sequence does not exist

LINE 1: ...."domain"::text ilike '%@%') ORDER BY  "website"....
```

Comment: Seems like you need to update the module which was changed by your colleague. Try to get to the backend by manually changing the URL to <my-domain>/`web` go to Apps and update it. If that's not possible, change to your docker container and update the odoo module by using a terminal. There are already some answers to the last part here on SO.

Comment: I tried updating the Odoo module using a terminal, but it doesn't work, still the same error

Comment: 1) Update your question to show the complete error message. 2) In `psql` use `\d` to see how the column is actually spelled e.g. lower case, mixed case or upper case and add that to your question.

Comment: i added the global error

Comment: Add the description of the table as shown in the database.